# Set TextBox Text programmatically and update the model

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm updating a `TextBox.Text` value in C# but the model binded to wasn't updated.
When I update that visually it works (commenting this line `myTextbox.Text="new value";` and inputing manually the value at runtime)

```
<TextBox Name="myTextbox" Text="{Binding myValue}"/>
```

Comment: Could you please check the Visual Studio debugger console (output view) to see if any binding error is thrown and post your error here? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view model you need to call notify of property changed for binding value.

```
private string _myValue;
public string MyValue
{
    get { return _value; }
    set
    {
        _myValue = value;
        NotifyOfPropertyChanged("MyValue");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you are talking about the MVVM it's already done and working as I mentionned.

Comment: I know MVVM is working, but when you modify MyValue from your viewmodel, view is not able to figure out that something is changed. NotifyOfPropertyChanged basically tells view that some property is changed and view update that property.

Comment: You mean to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in the View?

Comment: In your viemodel, make your viewmodel derive from property changed,

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx).

Comment: If you are talking about the MVVM it's already done and working as I mentionned.

Answer (score 0):

writing "new value" in your textbox(ui) its not the same as myTextbox.Text="new value" in your codebehind(c#)

so my firsst question would be why you need myTextbox.Text="new value"??

Comment: Because the "new value" is from `System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.SelectedPath;`

Comment: Is need to do the same but (for business reason), how could you update the viewmodel accordingly?